# How to compare the last words of the lines in a file

Tags: bash

I'm using a Raspberry Pi as a backup server. I use cron to run each backup job nightly and log the output to a file specific to each job. So each morning I have a bunch of log files (job1.log .. jobN.log). The log files are overwritten each time the job runs. I have another cron job (that runs after all the backup jobs) that sends me an email showing the last line of each log file. This all works as expected.

I'd like to be able to get a status in the subject of the email based on the last lines of the log files. When a backup job is successfully completed, the last line of the log file has some info followed by the word "completed" (which isn't included if the job fails). In my script that sends the email, I use "tail -1  >> summary.txt" for each log file, so summary.txt is a collection containing the last line of each logfile (and is included in the body of the email sent to me).

What I'd like to do is to check the last word of each line in summary.txt to see if all jobs completed successfully, and set the subject of the email appropriately (a simple "backup succeeded" or "backup failed" would be sufficient).

What would be the best way to do this? I know one possibility would be to use **awk '{print $NF}'** to get the last word of each line, but I'm not sure how to use that.

EDIT: As requested, here is the simplified code I'm currently using to send the "status" email to myself:

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -1 job1.log > summary.txt
tail -1 job2.log >> summary.txt
tail -1 job3.log >> summary.txt

mail -s "PI Backup Report" myemail@myhost  < summary.txt
```

I know I could create an additional file with just the last lines by adding

```
awk '{print $NF}' summary.txt > results.txt
```

to the above script before the "mail" line, but then I still need to parse the results.txt file. How would I determine the status based on that file? Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Are you using the `mail` command?

Comment: Consider making life easier for yourself by writing out the info in an easily parsed format, e.g. `echo "$?" > job42.status`. That way it doesn't matter if the human readable output changes slightly from "job 42 completed" to "job 42 completed." or completely to "task 42 finished successfully"

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions. As requested, I have edited the original to include the code I'm currently using to send the "status" email to myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measure total vs success lines in summary.txt.

- `xargs echo` to trim results of excess whitespace
- `grep` with regex specifying the line should end in "completed"
- `wc -l` for line count
- Set the title using an `if` statement

```sh
TOTAL=$(wc -l < summary.txt | xargs echo)
SUCCESS=$(grep -e 'completed$' summary.txt | wc -l)
title=$(if [ $TOTAL = $SUCCESS ]; then echo 'All Succeeded'; else echo "$SUCCESS/$TOTAL succeeded"; fi)
echo $title # or pass into mail command as subject
```

Comment: Excellent -- this gives me the missing pieces I needed! Thank you!